# Python capitalise first letter of words within nested lists

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Using python 2.7

How can I write a function that will capitalise the first letter of a string regardless of the rest of it (i.e not using `.capitalize()`) then using another function that takes a nested list as arguments, apply the first function in a nested for loop?
Eg.

```
def capital_first():
   #some code

def capital_nested([['heLLo','hi'],['giddAy'',goodday'],['gooDbye,'seeYA','adios']])
   #some code
   capital_first()
```

with the output another nested list with the capitalised letters

```
[['HeLLo','Hi'],['GiddAy'',Goodday'],['GooDbye,'SeeYA','Adios']]
```

I currently have

```
def cap_first(word):
    newone = word[0].upper()
    return newone

def capitalize_nested(x):
    newlist = []
    for item in x:
        for word in item:
            newlist.append(cap_first(word))
    print newlist
```

output

```
['M', 'M', 'Y', 'Y', 'T', 'T', 'T']
```

I know this is because I have indexed `word[0]` but not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recreate the inner list inside your loop:

```
def capitalize_nested(x):
    newlist = []
    for item in x:
        newlist2 = []
        for word in item:
            newlist2.append(cap_first(word))
        newlist.append(newlist2)
    print newlist
```

Answer (score 2):

```
newone = word[0].upper()
```

With this, the rest of the word are discarded. Instead, append the rest like this:

```
newone = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks that was the missing part of the puzzle!